# R igraph incidence matrix to graph object

Tags: r, igraph

I have one possibly very stupid question.
I have following matrix:

```
inc <- matrix(sample(0:1, 15, repl=TRUE), 5, 5)
colnames(inc) <- letters[1:5]
rownames(inc) <- letters[1:5]
```

Now when I use igraph to create an igraph object, the object understands rownames and colnames as two seperate nodes.

```
library(igraph)
incg <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(inc)
plot(incg)
```

[image]

The result is obviously kinda useless. Maybe I'm completely misunderstanding igraph, but how do I get it to understand that colnames and rownames are the same node?

So I would want a network object that shows the relation of a->b as a directed edge.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: its because you are using `graph_from_incidence_matrix()` when I think what you want is `graph_from_adjacency_matrix()`

Comment: Oh yeah thank you, that's probably it.